# Electronic Power steering dashboard light

Tags: electrical

I have a kia forte 2009 but my EPS dash light is always on and my steering is OK,
My question is should I ignore this light and continue driving?

Comment: You sure it's EPS and not ESP? ESP is your stability control

Comment: Have you ever tried steering the car without powersteering, when the ignition is off? It's really hard to do. Imagine you suddenly, unexpectedly, have to do that in traffic. It can create lethally dangerous situations. Your problem is likely not that critical, and it probably won't suddenly stop alltogether, but it's still dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not ignore it. Steering is with the brakes the most important safety critical system in the car. Either steering or brakes failing can be fatal.

The systems are usually designed in such a manner that they don't fail by suddenly turning violently to the left when there's oncoming traffic, but even the mere possibility of this happening would be a major concern.

If you ignore it, you'll soon find the car failed the next mandatory inspection.

However, do note that EPS and ESP are two different things, as user9181 correctly noticed. Even the ESP light would usually mean the inspection is failed.